# Intercalate pictures and items in beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, diagrams, itemize

I'm preparing a presentation in which I'd like to have pictures in a new slide between `\item`s. The final result should look like:

Slide 1:

- I want to discuss:

1) Cars

Slide 2:

[Picture of a car]

Slide 3:

- I want to discuss:

1) Cars

2) Airplane

Slide 4:

[Picture of an airplane]

And so on...

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `againframe` command allows you to do that by storing the labeled frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=myframe]{The list}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Car
        \item Airplane
        \item Watermelon
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    A car picture here
\end{frame}
\againframe<2>{myframe}
\begin{frame}
    An airplane picture here
\end{frame}
\againframe<3>{myframe}
\begin{frame}
    An watermelon picture here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```